# trailing slash for a php web service

Tags: php

I'm new in webservice and I created a little example.

The code is:

```
$json_encoded = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json_encoded, true);
if ( count($array) ) {
   echo "OK: data received";
} else {
   echo "NO data received";
}
```

This little script is located at `http://www.example.com/api/check/index.php`

Now if I try to use POSTMAN software to test it wth a json payload, it works great if I use a POST call at `http://www.example.com/api/check/` :

```
OK: data received
```

But if I try to send a request to the same address without trailing slash `http://www.example.com/api/check` i get:

```
NO data received
```

Is there a way to get it working for both calls (with and without trailing slash) ?

I cannot edit server config, so i'd like to get it working editing `index.php` or adding an `.htaccess` here `http://www.example.com/api/check/`

Any suggest?